# Oracle 11gR2 Installation on Oracle linux 7 - Prerequisite condition failed for OS kernel parameter “semmni”

Tags: linux, database, oracle, database-administration, failed-installation

while Installing oracle 11gr2 on oracle Linux 7. The prerequisite condition to test whether the OS kernel parameter "semmni" is failed with below error.[image]
Please find the screenshot of it.

Below is the kernel parameters which are configured in the etc/sysctl.conf file.

```
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576    
fs.file-max = 6815744    
kernel.shmall = 2097152    
kernel.shmmax = 2147483648     
kernel.shmmni = 4096
#semaphores: semmsl, semmns, semopm, semmni
kernel.sem = 250 256000 100 1024    
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500    
net.core.rmem_default=262144    
net.core.rmem_max=4194304   
net.core.wmem_default=262144
net.core.wmem_max=1048586
```

Any idea why it is failing?

Comment: Yes, you’re missing kernel.semmni in your config file. The requirements are stated here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCGJCEA

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the kernel.semmni=128.
Read the requirements here.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCGJCEA

I recommend you to install all requirements at once using the preinstall package. Find the link here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/oracle-rdbms-server-11gr2-pre-install-rpm-for-oracle-linux-6-has-been-released

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem. I checked my **/proc/sys/kernel/sem** and the values are exactly as its been mentioned in the Oracle document.
Plus, despite having all the packages, its still showing me **FAILED** when it check the packages.

Answer (score -1):

It is fixable, you could just click the Fix button and execute the specified script to fix it.